# MATLAB - Connect different arrays/matrixes to a bigger matrix

Tags: matlab

I have heard that it is possible to connect different matrixes into a bigger matrix in Matlab. In that case I have tried searching around but haven`t found anything yet so I thought I ask here.

In that case I have some matrixes I want to connect to a bigger one. I have one matrix of random arrivals times into a city, and another matrix with random departures from the city, and other matrixes with different types electric cars with driving range and battery status.

Is it possible to do this, and in that case how? Im not asking to provide some code, but giving links to references where I can learn this would be really thankful:) thank you.

Comment: Look for [cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) or [struct](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html). You could also find a comarision [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-vs-struct-arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks dude, really appreciate! I will soon provide some code here so it may be useful for others :)

Comment: Maybe repmat will work for you.